# Populating JSON In $window.onload AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the following code I am using to populate a JSON in one of my controllers:

```
$rootScope.commands.forEach(function(element, index, array){
                $rootScope.voiceEvents[element] = function() {
                    $scope.$broadcast(element, element + ' from VoiceControlCtrl');
                }
            });  
      alert(JSON.stringify($rootScope.voiceEvents));
```

The problem with the above is that it breaks the app periodically since ,from time to time, $rootScope.commands is undefined, depending on (I assume) how fast some other controllers or views are loaded.

I have been attempting to implement the following fix:

```
 $window.onload = function(commands){ 
       //alert($rootScope.commands);    
       $rootScope.commands.forEach(function(element, index, array){
            $rootScope.voiceEvents[element] = function() {
                $scope.$broadcast(element, element + ' from VoiceControlCtrl');
            }
        });  
        alert(JSON.stringify($rootScope.voiceEvents));
  };
```

The second version works, except for the fact that $rootScope.voiceEvents comes out empty. Why is that? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Add $scope.apply()

Comment: Add at which point?